# NEST Match Query Issue

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm currently working on a NEST searcher for a phones database. I've had very little luck with the dynamic version of things in terms of making it so that a user can filter certain terms to search for in the frontend.

This is because NEST doesn't like replacing a field "f.something" with a variable. Due to this I've gone to static because I believe I can do that with some object instantiation.

However, now even though I'm getting valid NEST responses back they're always empty even though there's obviously a result to be had. Such as "Name" for field and "iPhone" for query. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

P.S. The commented-out code used to have "bool" and "should" checks in but similarly I kept getting no results.

```
private ISearchResponse<MasterProduct> SearchThis(ElasticClient client, string query, string field, int pageSize, int recordNumber)
        {
            var searchLayout = new SearchRequest<MasterProduct>
            {
                Size = pageSize,
                From = recordNumber,
                Query = new MatchQuery
                {
                    Field = field,
                    Query = query,
                    Fuzziness = Fuzziness.Auto,
                    PrefixLength = 2,
                    Lenient = true,
                    FuzzyRewrite = MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBlendedFreqs(10)
                }
            };
            var searchResponse = client.Search<MasterProduct>(searchLayout);
            return searchResponse;
            }

            /*var searchResponse = client.Search<MasterProduct>(s => s
                .From(recordNumber)
                .Size(pageSize)
                .Query(q => q
                .Match(a => a
                    .Field(f => f.MasterProductName) 
                    .Query(query)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .PrefixLength(2)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .Lenient()
                    .FuzzyRewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBlendedFreqs(10))
                    )

                .Match(b => b
                    .Field(f => f.ManufacturerName)
                    .Query(query)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .PrefixLength(2)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .Lenient()
                    .FuzzyRewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBlendedFreqs(10))
                    )

                .Match(c => c
                    .Field(f => f.MasterAttributes)
                    .Query(query)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .PrefixLength(2)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
                    .Lenient()
                    .FuzzyRewrite(MultiTermQueryRewrite.TopTermsBlendedFreqs(10))
                    )
                )
            );
            Console.WriteLine(searchResponse.Hits.Count());

            foreach (var hit in searchResponse.Documents)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(hit.MasterProductId);

            }*/
    }
```

Comment: "NEST doesn't like replacing a field "f.something" with a variable" - can you elaborate on what you mean? Are you looking for something like `.Suffix(...)`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#_complex_field_name_expressions

Comment: @RussCam thanks for responding Russ. Essentially, I want to search on a certain field in NEST depending on an inputted variable. So "MasterProductId" would be input and the query would search on that field. However I can't find a way to do this, it seems fields to search all need to be hard coded. Is this the case? Thanks again :)

Comment: The `Field` type has an implicit conversion from `string`, so you can pass the `string` input for the field. Note that strings are taken verbatim and not cased as expressions or `PropertyInfo` are, so if you're rolling with the defaults, the string value will need to be camel-cased e.g. `masterProductName`.

Comment: @RussCam excellent thank you that worked, now I just need to fix how I can't query numbers for some reason haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RussCam answered the question in the comments above.
To reiterate, pass only strings in as parameters to fields, not other datatypes.
Camelcase is also necessary for this to work.